# javascript, jQuery: How to re-listen for click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, listener, onclicklistener

I am listening for click events on the class `notification-link`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.notifications-link').click(
        function(){
            $('.notifications-popup').addClass('show')
        }
    )
});
```

Works fine. The problem is, if I append a new Element with the class `notification-link` to the DOM, jQuery doesn't listen for it = if you clicked on the appended Element, nothing happens.
How can I fix that?

Comment: you need attach even handler to those newly created elements dynamically.  You can do so by using jquery.

Comment: How do I do this with jQuery? That's basically the whole question :-)

Comment: read thru this link. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

`$('.notifications-link').click(function(){...})`

use

`$(document).on("click", ".notifications-link", function(){...});`

this way you're attaching the event to the document and then checking to see if the click landed on ".notifications-link" and will work will all newly added ".notifications-link"'s

Comment: awesome. works. thanks. :) .

Comment: @klvler - happy to help. if you would like to learn more check [this page](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) out. if this resolved your problem please hit the check mark as well. good luck.

Comment: hitting it since seven minutes - is saying there is still one to go

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delegation for the events to work on the elements added via JS.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '.notifications-link', function (e) {
        $('.notifications-popup').addClass('show');
    });
});
```

For detailed explanation about how Jquery event method like on, click etc works please check this post:
http://elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/

Comment: that article explains in depth how actually things works.

Comment: it explains 4 methods, three of which are deprecated.